# Method Chaining Performance Issues

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, method-chaining

I'm looking for recommendations/suggestions. I have a long-running process that I'm trying to optimize. This is the longest running process at 1 min 48sec per call to return a populated list. I'm looping over this with 1000 records per request so you can imagine how quickly the minutes can add up. I have optimized all other methods to less than 10 secs per 1000. I would love to be able to speed this up.

- GetLoans() retrieves data from the db and sends it to GetLoanList() to create a Collection to be sent to a restful webservice.
- GetRequestedWatches() returns a string like "1,2' so that's really quick.
- variables preceded with a '_' are class level properties that are loaded on instantiation.

I've tried Eager Loading and Lazy Loading. Eager loading has been the best performant so far.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
private List<SBLead> GetLoanList(IEnumerable<LoanCategoryMonitor> loans)
{
    return (loans.Where(selectedItem => selectedItem.Loan != null)
        .Select(selectedItem => new SBLead
        {
            ApiKey = _settings.apiKey,
            CrmId = selectedItem.LoanNumber.ToString(),
            CrmName = _crmName,
            LoanType = selectedItem.Loan.Loan_Type,
            Email = selectedItem.Loan.abcBorrower?.EMail_Address,
            FirstName = selectedItem.Loan?.Borr_First_Name,
            LastName = selectedItem.Loan?.Borr_Last_Name,
            Address = selectedItem.Loan?.Address,
            City = selectedItem.Loan?.City,
            State = selectedItem.Loan?.State,
            Zip = selectedItem.Loan?.Zip,
            Phone = string.Empty,
            WatchTypes = GetRequestedWatches(selectedItem.Category.GetEnumFromString<Category>()),
            UserEmail = _defaultLoanOfficerEmail,
            UserName = _defaultLoanOfficerName
        })).ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<LoanCategoryMonitor> GetLoans()
{
    var loanCollection = _be.LoanCategoryMonitors
        .Include(c => c.Loan)
        .Where(r => r.ReadyForUpdate == true && r.LoanExtracts == null &&
                    r.Category != Category.None.ToString())
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();

    return loanCollection;
}
```

Comment: So where is the time actually being spent? Querying the db? Elsewhere? Are you sure you've measured correctly and properly identified what is causing the slowdown? If you're doing this a lot, concurrently, then I'd strongly suggest moving to `async/await` on any methods that perform IO.

Comment: @spender GetLoanList() takes almost 2 minutes to return the List<SBLead> containing 1000 entities

Comment: Do you know why? That seems like an awful long time for a query to complete.

Comment: No, I don't know why. That's why it's here. I am assuming it's because it's loading the values from the child entities is slowing it down.

Comment: Does `GetRequestedWatches(selectedItem.Category.GetEnumFromString<Category>())` hit the db?

Comment: No that just returns a short string based on enum values. It's quick

Comment: So turn off all lazy-loading. As far as I can see, `GetLoanList` shouldn't need to hit the db, right? Remove `virtual` from all model properties and re-run your code. As it stands, that should throw a bunch of NullReferenceExceptions. You should now add the appropriate `Include(c => c.Loan.abcBorrower)` etc. so the the data is pulled from the db at query-time. You should also check `selectedItem.Loan != null` at query time, not over a materialized list, if possible.

Comment: Lazy Loading should be off. Inspection of the collection GetLoans() displays the Loan entity without the debugger making a call to the db to load it.

Comment: Split the code into different steps and debug to see where the bottleneck is. Try removing GetRequestedWatches. Also, why are you returning IEnumerable<> instead of IReadOnlyList<> or List<>? You might as well not even call ToList<>.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. also hitting GetRequestedWatches 1000 times looks a bit smelly, hit it once for all the things you need and add them from memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I was missing an Include for abcBorrower. The new execution speed is under almost instantaneous and I can live with that. that's a 1 min 48 sec saving per 1000 records. Thanks for the input

[image]

```
Email = selectedItem.Loan.abcBorrower?.EMail_Address,
```

Comment: Still 2 seconds for a 1000 records seems slow

Comment: I'm not done yet. I've increased performance 1000% so far. I need to stop and get new benchmarks now. This one here was a huge time savings.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.  This kind of thing is why I tend to recommend a SP for the non-trivial stuff.  It usually saves heaps of dev time as well as execution time.  I must confess I roll my eyes a bit when I see the "how do I convert this SQL to LINQ" questions on SO!